# Open Id accounts with ASP.Net Identity

Tags: openid, asp.net-identity-2

We are new at ASP.Net Identity so please bear with me, we're in the analysis stage. We are developing a web app to sell to our clients which they will host. We don't want to be in the login/security business so we want to use ASP.Net Identity to allow them to have logins using Microsoft and Google.

I am assuming that each of our clients would have to create a Microsoft Account and/or a Google Developer Client Id for our app. How does a company manage these ids? Say our clients wanted 2 or more people being able to mange the developer ids how would that work? I don't see how you can associate another email  address with the account the manages the apps/projects.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that each user creates a local account for your app, and associates it with a 3rd party account (google/fb), so you don't store any passwords in your app, you just store an association and rely on the OpenId provider to authenticate first, and then your app signs in the appropriate user after looking up the associated open id login.

Comment: Hao, I'm referring to the account for the developer keys.